# How to Check if code running on Inventor Desktop or Inventor Server?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Within an iLogic rule, how can I check if the code is running on Inventor Desktop or Inventor Server?
For example, we know that message boxes are not allowed in IDA/APS; therefore, within an iLogic rule I want to do the following;

If InventorDesktop Then
MessageBox.Show("This is Inventor Desktop")
else
'InventorServer is active and therefore, don't show the MessageBox and take an alternative approach
End If

One possible approach would be to check for active process because Inventor Desktop is Inventor.exe and Inventor Server as I understand it is InventorCoreConsole.exe

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need not have to ask Inventor for this information. You should be able to package or code or configure your Desktop addin differently from DA addin.

Should you choose not to do that and still want the system to tell you what mode you are in, you can check to see if the environment variable `DAS_WORKITEM_ID` is defined:

```cs
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DAS_WORKITEM_ID");
```

Also see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62895841/how-to-check-if-we-are-on-design-automation-cloud-or-not).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured out how to do this via iLogic by checking the value of ThisDoc.Document.Parent.SoftwareVersion.ProductName

On Inventor Desktop, the returns "Inventor"; whereas, in Inventor Design Automation it returns "Inventor Interoperability".

So, this can easily be incorporated into a rule such as the following;

If ThisDoc.Document.Parent.SoftwareVersion.ProductName = "Inventor" Then

'Code is running on Inventor Desktop
MessageBox.Show("Inventor Desktop", "Product Name")

End If